# What is that sugar like thing in the porcelain body of NH2 fuses,315 amp,400v?

Tags: fuses

On breaking down a 415v,315 amp Siemens NH2 fuses, I saw some white sugar like material.
What is that?

Comment: Probably melted ceramic

Comment: Safety Note: Be VERY careful cutting open electrical ceramics.  Some are composed of beryllium oxide, which is highly toxic (read: Potentially Fatal) when inhaled.  When fired and solid, it is safe, but cutting, grinding, sanding, or generating any dust is seriously bad.

Comment: @RDrast Is beryllium oxide still used nowadays? I thought it were banned from industry some years ago due to its toxicity (old equipment could still employ parts containing it, of course).

Comment: @LorenzoDonati - Absolutely it is still in use.  There are many manufacturers providing custom made pieces as well.  Primarily, it is used for thermal transfer in many power semiconductors, and some power vacuum tubes, but any high temperature ceramic application should be considered suspect and not a subject to just grind, cut, or file to "See what's inside".  It might be your last view.

Comment: @RDrast Ouch! I thought it was replaced by silicone-based compounds in almost all applications! Good to know, thanks!

Comment: Also, an NH2 fuse isn't exactly some piece of consumer equipment...

Answer (score 10):

Since you don't add a direct link or an image, I can only guess it is an [High Rupturing Capacity (HRC) Fuse](http://electricalbaba.com/hrc-fuse-construction-working-and-characteristics/), a.k.a. High Breaking Capacity (HBC) Fuse.

In those fuses the fusible element (the conductor that gets melted when an overload occurs) is embedded in a sand-like compound used to [quench the possible electric arc](https://www.electrical4u.com/arc-interruption-theory/) that can be generated when interrupting a current in a circuit capable of delivering an high level of energy.

Without that powder the fuse may explode and its fragments could damage other parts of the equipment the fuse it's intended to protect, causing more failures, even fires!

See also [this link](https://www.electrical4u.com/electrical-fuse-hrc-fuse-high-rupturing-capacity/).

Answer (score 9):

Cartridge fuses required to have high breaking capacity (HBC) are filled with **granular quartz** with high chemical purity. The grain sizes are in the region of 300μm. The grain size is tailored to suit the element thickness and desired performance.

The quartz material conducts some of the heat energy away from the fuse element to the body and therefore to obtain consistent performance it is necessary that the packing density is maintained during production. This factor will have a very significant effect on the behaviour at high current levels because a low packing density may allow the arcs to expand more rapidly, affecting the column voltage and thus the rate of current change.

To ensure uniformity of packing, the quartz is poured into the open ends of fuses which are complete except for the pressing on of their final outer end cap and tag assemblies. The fuses are vibrated and, if necessary, extra quartz is added during this process to ensure that the internal space is packed as densely as possible. The fuse is then completed by adding the final outer end cap and tag assembly.

The quartz melts and 'fuses' to create a glass like material when the fuse operates under fault conditions. This helps to extinguish the arcing within the fuse.